# Interior painting

Tags: walls, ceiling

My. Maintenance  wanted to paint this apartment but the temperature is 28 degrees today, no snow but inside the apartment is no heat,would it be still ok to paint the apartment?

Comment: If that temperature is in Fahrenheit ...
If the apartment is under 70 degrees I would not paint it. The condensation, cooling of the paint as it hits those cold walls will have an effect on the adhesion of the paint as well as how the paint will set up on the surface. If the paint is being sprayed on - NO WAY should you spray paint at anything when it is under 70 degrees unless you want to redo it when the temperature rises to 70 degrees or more ..

Comment: I've been painting all day today with the 'stat at 50... It's latex which is not my usual paint, and it's been *way* slow drying and so thick it's halfway to jello... My alkyds I paint down to 50 and have done LPU at 37F and they don't get jelloish ... Latex is weird...